# Does knockout 'attr' always assume input require escape, is it possible to turn it off?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, escaping

If one were to bind `attr: { href: url }`, does it always escape url according to rfc2396?

I have recently encounter issue where `&amp;` in json response is converted to `&amp;amp;` by knockout, I am guessing knockout has no way of knowing it's double-encoded (html then json), and thus convert any `&` into entities.

Should we always give raw url to `attr` binding, but not for `html` binding? what's the rule of thumb here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSON.stringify('"some text"')
```

[KnockoutJS postJSON method escapes my string why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003415/knockoutjs-postjson-method-escapes-my-string-why)